# Integrate with eCDF quickly in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I have an integral equation of the form 
$$
T_1(x) = \int_0^x g(T_1(y)) \ d\hat{F}_n(y)
$$
where $\hat{F}_n$ is the empirical cdf and $g$ is a function. 
I have a contraction mapping and so I am trying to solve the integral equation by using the Banach Fixed Point theorem sequence.

However, this runs very slowly in R and I am thinking it is because I am integrating using the sum() function for $x \in \hat{F}_n$ over and over again.

Is there a faster way to integrate using the empirical distribution with a function such as integrate()?

Comment: Although this is really an R question rather than a stats question (and therefore probably belongs on stackoverflow)...  could you post your code?  In R, there are often multiple opportunities to obtain great runtime performance improvements, and w/o seeing the code, it's hard to tell which, if any, might apply.

Answer (score 14):

Defining the empirical distribution function 
$$
  \hat{F}_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I_{[x_i,\infty)}(t) \, ,
$$
it follows that
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\,d\hat{F}_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) \, .
$$
Hence, you don't need to use `integrate()` to solve this problem. This kind of `R` code

```
x <- rnorm(10^6)
g <- function(t) exp(t) # say
mean(g(x))
```

should be super fast because it is vectorized.

Comment: please note, I have added a related question as to why the integral of a function with respect to the empirical distribution, is the average of function evaluated at the observed points. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340290/proof-that-integral-of-a-function-with-respect-to-the-empirical-distribution-is